# Reintroduce $HTTP_POST_VARS in PHP 5.3

Tags: php

I need to run a [**legacy** PHP application](http://www.edisplayecommerce.it/) in a shared hosting environment. I have promised my customer I'll support that legacy application for some time but I found that it doesn't work because it widely uses the deprecated `$HTTP_POST_VARS`.

Downgrading PHP is not an option. Patching the application *could* be infeasible because the PHP files are generated from a Windows executable file (I'm not kidding!) and every time the site is regenerated from desktop we could lose modifications.

I'm asking if there is a way to tell PHP to reintroduce `$HTTP_POST_VARS` for all websites on a host or just for a particular vhost. Any other option/suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Now that I think about it, this question looks suitable for serverfault *too*...

Comment: argh.... these type of clients.... A pain i understand.

Comment: I thought that even though it was deprecated, `$HTTP_POST_VARS` should still work.  It's not superglobal, so maybe you need to do `global $HTTP_POST_VARS;` or access `$GLOBALS['HTTP_POST_VARS'];`?

Comment: If your shared host allows you to set a custom php.ini then you can turn on `register_long_arrays` http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-long-arrays

Comment: @RocketHazmat I have tested with 5.3.8 and it doesn't work. Anyway I have almost come to a possible solution to share :)

Comment: @MrCode interesting but removed from PHP 5.4.0. I run the shared hosting so I can modify the configuration but I don't want to lose future upgrades

Comment: define them in the config file with reference

Comment: runkit.superglobal "$HTTP_POST_VARS" may work in your php.ini or htaccess

Comment: `Windows executable file (I'm not kidding!) ` .... can't stop laughing

Comment: @j_mcnally if runkit works in vhost environment you win the accept mark :) Let's see if YaST finds it

Comment: Baba has the right way to do this w/o runkit.

Comment: @Baba at least I linked the app's website :):) +1 to your comment

Comment: look at what love has gotten you into ....

Comment: you should tell your client to start live in the future not the past, i have the same problem like you old code on new php version trying to patch it if that doesn't work i will either write the entire code from scratch or tell the client to move to a server that supports an older version of php. it's his problem not yours and you should not make promises about thing that you can't control.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do this

config.php

```
$HTTP_POST_VARS = &$_POST;
$HTTP_GET_VARS = &$_GET;
$HTTP_COOKIE_VARS = &$_COOKIE;
```

.htaccess

```
php_value auto_prepend_file /path/to/config.php
```

PHP doc [auto_prepend_file string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file)

> Specifies the name of a file that is automatically parsed before the main file. The file is included as if it was called with the require function, so include_path is used.
>
> The special value none disables auto-prepending.

EDIT: To be extra thorough, these are the other superglobals that could also be aliased:

```
$HTTP_SERVER_VARS = &$_SERVER;
$HTTP_POST_FILES = &$_FILES;
$HTTP_SESSION_VARS = &$_SESSION;
$HTTP_ENV_VARS = &$_ENV;
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for with that runkit stuff.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like

```
$HTTP_POST_VARS = $_POST;
```

If you can include the code in the pages, that should work. Of course you have to have access to the source code and recompile the exe in windows, but you said *could*.

Comment: That would be the solution in the case the PHP files are stored in the program's directory and not compiled within the executable

Answer (score 2):

`register_long_arrays` works for 5.3, but they nuked this in php 5.4

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-long-arrays

And yes, this setting is labled `PHP_INI_PERDIR`, so you can set it via individual .htaccess or individual ini files, as well as set it globally.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the following can work.

First, create an `edisplaypatch.php` somewhere with following code

```
<?php

if (getenv('EDISPLAY_PATCH')) {
    if (!isset($HTTP_GET_VARS)) $HTTP_GET_VARS = $_GET;
    if (!isset($HTTP_POST_VARS)) $HTTP_POST_VARS = $_POST;
    if (!isset($HTTP_COOKIE_VARS)) $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS = $_COOKIE;
}

?>
```

This code can be generalized and reused with any other program requiring the old long arrays

Then in Apache's vhost configuration add

```
SetEnv EDISPLAY_PATCH true
```

Reload Apache.

Test code works: if SetEnv is not present doesn't show nothing, if present shows what you send as `rnd` parameter in querystring

```
<?php
echo $HTTP_GET_VARS['rnd'];
//phpinfo();
?>
```

Little drawback: I'm including a file on EVERY PHP request