# PHP contact form suddenly stopped sending e-mails

Tags: php, contact-form

The code wasn't touched at all but a form that previously worked fine it's not sending e-mails anymore. I'm not used to PHP and I'm not sure if maybe something is deprecated. Pay no attention to the URLs as I have modified them to make this post.

**The HTML:**

```
<form action="http://url/mail_cast.php" method="post" id="contacto">

        <br />
        <table width="208" align="center">
<tr>
                  <td width="44" valign="top" class="Estilo24">Nombre</td>
            <td width="147" class="Estilo72"><input name='Nombre' type='text' class="Estilo73" size="22" /></td>
          <td width="1" rowspan="4" class="Estilo72">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" class="Estilo24">Email</td>
                  <td height="5" valign="top" class="Estilo72"><input name='Email' type='text' class="Estilo73" size="22" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" class="Estilo24">Mensaje</td>
                  <td colspan="2" class="Estilo72"><textarea name='Mensaje' cols="17" rows="7" class="Estilo73"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="3" align="center" class="Estilo72">
                      <input name="submit" type='submit' class="Estilo73" value='Enviar mensaje' /></td>
                </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
        Los datos facilitados al enviar al rellenar el formulario formarán parte de la Base de Datos de la Clínica, para más información consultar el <a href="../cat/aviso.html">Aviso legal </a>de nuestra web.
</form>
```

And the **mail_cast.php** where the form is being submitted:

```
<?php

$msg="Ha recibido un comentario en la web";
/*$msg = "Ha ricevuto una e-mail dal formulario di Contattaci del sito ... \n\nQuesto è il contenuto del messaggio inviato\n\n";*/
//$enviarMensaje="";
$field_name = array_keys($HTTP_POST_VARS); // guardamos todos los nombres de los "fields" existentes en el formulario
$value_name = array_values($HTTP_POST_VARS);// guardamos todos los valores en sus respectivas variables
//count($field_name)
for ($i=0;$i<4;$i++)//Numero de variables
{
   $msg .= "".$field_name[$i].": ".$value_name[$i]."\n\n"; // $msg reune el nombre de la variable y su valor
}

$recipient = "contacturl@mail"; // el mail deseado
$subject = "formulario web"; // el titulo del mail
//$mailheaders = "From: PUSH UP \n";
$mailheaders = "From: X<http://www.url.com> \n"; // quien lo manda y el dominio
$mailheaders .= "Reply-To: ".$mail."\n\n";   // responder a: Importante! si quieres que el replay:to funcione tienes 
                  //que tener en el formulario un field que tiene como nombre "mail".

mail($recipient, $subject, $msg, $mailheaders);// mandamos el mail con los todos los datos
header('location:http://www.url.com/cast/gracias.html'); // y vamos a la pagina en donde nos dan las gracias por haber llenado en formulario
?>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, there are some deprecated things: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978293/reintroduce-http-post-vars-in-php-5-3

Comment: Maybe simply your SMTP server is dead or is blocking your outgoing mail.
Run `nc xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 25` in Linux - you should get 220 code in terminal if it is alive.